# New physical address required by Google Play when publishing app

Tags: android, google-play, publish

So I just wanted to know about this new requirement that they have when publishing apps on Google Play. Do you have to also submit it with free apps, or is it only for paid apps? Also, I feel uncomfortable with it because I develop at home and I don't have a PO Box, so I dont want to give away my street address. Is there any way I could avoid it? If not, what would happen if I put a fake address? I mean, how would they find out? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an app distribution channel, not programming. Non-technical questions regarding distribution channels are [explicitly off-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: I dont know where else to ask it as this is one of the most popular forums for questions about development in general...

Comment: Here are a couple dozen Android developer support sites, in a variety of languages: http://www.andglobe.com/ You could also try [the Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You would get better help on official support forums: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers

Comment: Or it could just be answered here I hate the strictness of this forum like damn

Comment: https://www.change.org/p/google-remove-the-need-for-developers-to-reveal-their-physical-addresses-publicly-on-google-play

Comment: for goodness sake!! If you know, just answer, if you don't know they silence is golden

Answer (score 0):

https://www.greenbot.com/article/2685242/android-developers-must-now-list-physical-address-in-play-store.html

The gist is..."this is just the way it is!" put up with it.